# mac terminal § key issue

Tags: macos, mac, terminal

I have stange behavior of `§` key in terminal, when i press in on fresh terminal i have  `<ffffffff>` how can i find where the `§` key is defined? I use zsh with default configuration, and i have some basic alias in `.bash_profile` can't find where this can be defined, reinstaling zsh does't help.

can't find solution on internet either, looks like no one has it before :(

here is how it works:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rwczj.jpg

Comment: I'm not sure what key you're talking about... Do you mean the command key?  If so, it's a "metakey" and gets treated a bit differently than other keys, much like the Windows key on MS Windows keyboards.  Programatically, it even has a different "keydown" event (event.metaKey vs event.keydown).  [Here's some info on it from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_key).

Comment: its not meta key, its first key below esc § if you google `mac keyboard` its the key below esc

Comment: What country/language is your keyboard from? Mac US English "qwerty" keyboard layouts don't have a dedicated key for that character. On US Mac keyboards you have to hit option-6 to get an "§". Are you running macOS's built-in `/Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app` ? If so, what settings do you have under Preferences > Profiles > Advanced > International ?

Comment: you right i have it checked, works well when i unchecked it, i was looking in wrong place. Many thanks 

Comment: @Codex ahh... Russian keyboard.  On the US keyboard that's the tilde.  As it's an international keyboard it must be a unicode character, though I'm not certain why it would act strangely.